# Multiple rule Apache rewrite

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, rewrite

I am trying to set up a hierarchy five levels deep with `mod_rewrite`. This is what I have put together at this point. It works for the last two levels (the first and second rule) but not after that. Any help would be well appreciated.

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /mr/index.php?product_group=$1&product_family=$2&product_category=$3&product_sub_category=$4&product=$5 [C]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /mr/index.php?product_group=$1&product_family=$2&product_category=$3&product_sub_category=$4 [C] 
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /mr/index.php?product_group=$1&product_family=$2&product_category=$3 [C]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /mr/index.php?product_group=$1&product_family=$2 [C] 
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /mr/index.php?product_group=$1 [L]
```

I am not a server tech. I am a developer and just can't figure this out. Each of these rules works fine by itself. I need the rule(s) to work from one level to five and every step in between. I need a drill down style navigation that is SEO friendly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you've chained all the rules together with the `[C]` flag. See [the documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_c) for an explanation of their meanings. You probably want `[L]` for "last" instead.

It's also worth noting that the rules will be run until the URL does not change any longer; so your second-to-last rule will likely create a rewrite loop, unless you have a rule before it similar to this:

```
RewriteRule ^/mr/index.php$ - [L]
```

**Edit:** For clarity, this is what I'd suggest as a starting point. You may get some insight from [the logging provided by `mod_rewrite`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging).

```
RewriteRule ^mr/index.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ /mr/index.php?product_group=$1&product_family=$2&product_category=$3&product_sub_category=$4&product=$5 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$         /mr/index.php?product_group=$1&product_family=$2&product_category=$3&product_sub_category=$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$                 /mr/index.php?product_group=$1&product_family=$2&product_category=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$                         /mr/index.php?product_group=$1&product_family=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$                                 /mr/index.php?product_group=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Fredden, Thanks but I do have a [L] on the last rule. I've tried a hundred combinations and am still not there. I'm not a server person but do need to get this working for a new project.

Comment: I was trying to say that you probably don't want the rules chained at all, but that each rule should stand alone. As it stands, only the first rule will ever be processed properly, the others will be skipped if the first doesn't match.

Comment: Fredden, That seems to work well - thanks! I still don't fully understand mod_rewrite and will try to fit in more research on it soon. There are some anomalies but nothing I can't overcome on the code side. See: [link] (http://ninog.com/mr/)

Comment: Given those examples, I'd add `/?` before the `$` on each of the rules (except the first). That means "optionally with a trailing slash." Also, it looks like I missed a `[C]` when I copied your code - change that for an `[L]`. So you'd end up with something like: `RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ /mr/inde...`  I'll edit my post.

Comment: That's perfect! Man I really appreciate your help.